# Не отправляется форма

Tags: jquery, html

Помогите найти ошибку. Вот это почему-то не срабатывает, т.е. не отправляет форму.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://github.com/malsup/form/raw/master/jquery.form.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var string =$("#form1").formSerialize();
    $("#click").click(function(){  
        $.load("md5.php",string,function(data){
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
    $("#1").hide();
    $("#1").show(1000);
    });
});
</script>
<div id='1'>
</div>
<form id ="form1">
<input type="text" name="a">
<input type="submit" id="click" value="test">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А какая вообще задача? Просто отправить форму?

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, что вы подгружаете методом $.load() ?
Во-вторых, укажите метод формы, не заставляйте браузер гадать на кофейной гуще, что вы от него хотите, т.е. вот:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="a">
    <input type="submit" id="click" value="test">
</form>
```

И третье: давать блокам цифровые айдишники (id='1') - плохой тон, если вообще допустимо (тут не уверен).

И еще у вас весело получается, что по клику на отправку формы у вас должна идти отправка и параллельно с этим - подгрузка. Вопрос: что это за махинации? ;)

Comment: Должна идти отправка и загрузка ответа от сервера

Comment: Ну так тогда вам нужно на аяксе отправлять форму! Использовать не функцию $.load(), а в идеале - $.ajax(), ну или ее упрощенную версию $.post()!

Answer (score 0):

А у вас эта страница с формой умеет обрабатывать то что вы отправляете? Если в form нет параметра action то POST и GET запросы передаются на страницу с которой отправлялись данные.